# Illegal implicit conversion from enum? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, types, enums

I get the error message 
Error: Illegal implicit conversion from '@enum$1main_c**' to '@enum$1main_c*'

```
//example.h
typedef enum {eg_1, eg_2} valType;


//main.c
#include "example.h"
void main(void)
{
 valType *testVal;
while(1)
 {
 read(x,y,*testval);
 }
}
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank's in advance

Comment: Based on the error message you need to `&testval` to get this to compile as _something_ is expecting an `valType**`. However, I don't know what `x`, `y` or `read()` are.

Comment: Is this the `read` from `unistd.h`? What types are `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the `read` from `unistd.h`, its last parameter has to be a `size_t`, not a `valType`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the source code for `read()` function. Probably it takes `testVal` as a pointer but you are passing as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, what I can say is testVal has an undefined value, it's an uninitialized pointer. I am *assuming* read will try to put something in testVal, so for now, change your code to :

```
//example.h
typedef enum {eg_1, eg_2} valType;


//main.c
#include "example.h"
void main(void)
{
 valType testVal;
while(1)
 {
 read(x,y, &testval);
 }
}
```

and let us know how it went.